# Creating named tables with macro (using data)

Tags: macros, sas

I want to create tables with the names store in macro variable
Currently my code creates only first of tables with correct naming .

My code

```
%let list = var1 var2 var3;
%put list;

%macro rob;
data dat_&list;
run;
%mend;

%rob;
```

Desired output should be that there are three tables with these names creted: `dat_var1, dat_var2, dat_var3.`
However now it creates `dat_var1, var2, var3`

What should i change in the code to make it work?

Comment: You have to loop through, remember that SAS is doing literal text replacement with the macros so you'd end up with : `data_var1 var2 var3` which is valid, but not what you want. See the SAS Macro Appendix for examples of looping here: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1qvxz5u3uru7yn1nk7q64ohvwak.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

Macros are a way to dynamically write SAS code.  You can use `options mprint;` to see what was generated.  In this simple case it was:

```
data dat_var1 var2 var3;
run;
```

What you want it to read is:

```
data dat_var1 dat_var2 dat_var3;
run;
```

So you need to loop through the `list` macro and create those values.

```
%macro rob();
%local i n;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&list));

data
%do i=1 %to &n;
   dat_%scan(&list,&i)
%end;
;
run;
%mend;

%rob;
```

Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `TRANWRD()` is an easy way to add prefix/suffix strings to a delimited list. Advantage is that it does not require conditional code and so does not need to be wrapped into a macro.  But make sure your list does NOT have multiple delimiters between words/tokens.

```
%let list = var1   var2     var3;
%let list=%sysfunc(compbl(&list));
%let dslist=dat_%sysfunc(tranwrd(&list,%str( ),%str( dat_)));

data &dslist ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular express. (\w+) means word characters, which will be replace with dat_(\w+) (here is $1 for \w+).

```
%let list = var1 var2 var3;
%put list;

%macro rob;
data %sysfunc(prxchange(s/(\w+)/dat_$1/,-1,&list));
run;
%mend;

%rob;
```